# After I change the fs/myext2/file.c read and write operation, my 'cat', 'cp', 'echo' are all killed

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I copy the fs/ext2/ as fs/myext2/, and have modified all the things I need to modify, and it all does well before I change the fs/myext2/file.c.
And it does well, when I change like this (

Add following codes into file.c, and the `new_sync_write` and `new_sync_read` functions are copied from fs/read_write.c.

And I also add another header `linux/uio.h`,

add `.read  = new_sync_read_crypt, .write = new_sync_write_crypt` to `const struct file_operations myext2_file_operations`).

```
ssize_t new_sync_write_crypt(struct file *filp, const char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *ppos){
    char *mybuf = buf;
    int i;
    /*for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        mybuf[i] += 25;
    }*/
    printk("haha write encrypt %ld\n",len);
    return new_sync_write(filp,mybuf,len,ppos);
}

ssize_t new_sync_read_crypt(struct file *filp, char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *ppos){

    ssize_t ret = new_sync_read(filp,buf,len,ppos);
    int i;
    /*for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
        buf[i] -= 25;*/
    printk("haha read encrypt %ld\n",len);
    return ret;
}
```

'does well' means that, under /mnt, I `echo "1234567" > test.txt`, and in log(`dmesg`) it does have the right output, and I can 'cp', 'cat'.

but after I move the `/**/`, all go wrong.
I cannot 'cat test.txt', it said `killed`.

```
root@ubuntu:/mnt# cat test.txt
killed
root@ubuntu:/mnt#
```

in log:

```
[ 5640.036210] BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at b733f000
[ 5640.036215] IP: [<f9072aa0>] new_sync_read_crypt+0xc0/0x100 [myext2]
[ 5640.036220] *pdpt = 0000000011da5001 *pde = 0000000004708067 *pte =     0000000000000000 
[ 5640.036222] Oops: 0002 [#21] SMP 
[ 5640.036225] Modules linked in: myext2(OE) rfcomm bnep crc32_pclmul vmw_balloon aesni_intel aes_i586 xts lrw gf128mul ablk_helper cryptd joydev input_leds serio_raw snd_ens1371 snd_ac97_codec gameport ac97_bus vmw_vsock_vmci_transport vsock snd_pcm snd_seq_midi uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops snd_seq_midi_event videobuf2_v4l2 snd_rawmidi btusb btrtl btbcm videobuf2_core btintel videodev bluetooth media snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer snd soundcore nfit 8250_fintek mac_hid vmw_vmci i2c_piix4 shpchp parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid psmouse vmwgfx ttm drm_kms_helper ahci libahci mptspi mptscsih pcnet32 mii syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops drm mptbase scsi_transport_spi pata_acpi fjes [last unloaded: myext2]
[ 5640.036249] CPU: 0 PID: 9011 Comm: cat Tainted: G      D    OE   4.6.0 #1
[ 5640.036250] Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 05/19/2017
[ 5640.036252] task: f549dc40 ti: d1da6000 task.ti: d1da6000
[ 5640.036253] EIP: 0060:[<f9072aa0>] EFLAGS: 00010206 CPU: 0
[ 5640.036255] EIP is at new_sync_read_crypt+0xc0/0x100 [myext2]
[ 5640.036256] EAX: b735f000 EBX: b733f000 ECX: d1da7f60 EDX: 00000000
[ 5640.036258] ESI: 00020000 EDI: 00000000 EBP: d1da7ed8 ESP: d1da7e88
[ 5640.036259]  DS: 007b ES: 007b FS: 00d8 GS: 00e0 SS: 0068
[ 5640.036260] CR0: 80050033 CR2: b733f000 CR3: 30ef0120 CR4: 003406f0
[ 5640.036265] Stack:
[ 5640.036265]  00000001 00020000 d1da7f60 b733f000 00020000 00000000 00000000 00020000
[ 5640.036268]  d1da7e94 00000001 f2bdac00 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[ 5640.036271]  ffa41c7b f2bdac00 f90729e0 d1da7f60 d1da7f2c c11ea28f d1da7f60 c6e50cf8
[ 5640.036274] Call Trace:
[ 5640.036277]  [<f90729e0>] ? myext2_empty_dir+0x170/0x170 [myext2]
[ 5640.036280]  [<c11ea28f>] __vfs_read+0x2f/0x100
[ 5640.036282]  [<c11ea76e>] ? rw_verify_area+0x5e/0x140
[ 5640.036284]  [<c11ea8bf>] vfs_read+0x6f/0x140
[ 5640.036286]  [<c11eb9e1>] SyS_read+0x51/0xb0
[ 5640.036288]  [<c100394d>] do_fast_syscall_32+0x8d/0x140
[ 5640.036291]  [<c17baa2e>] sysenter_past_esp+0x47/0x75
[ 5640.036292] Code: 8d 45 d8 ff 51 10 3d ef fd ff ff 89 c7 74 54 8b 45 dc 8b 4d b8 85 f6 8b 55 e0 89 01 8d 04 33 89 51 04 74 11 8d b4 26 00 00 00 00 <80> 2b 19 83 c3 01 39 d8 75 f6 89 74 24 04 c7 04 24 b5 b9 07 f9
[ 5640.036311] EIP: [<f9072aa0>] new_sync_read_crypt+0xc0/0x100     [myext2] SS:ESP 0068:d1da7e88
[ 5640.036320] CR2: 00000000b733f000
[ 5640.036322] ---[ end trace d357a556f62edff8 ]---
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but even more importantly,
please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).
So, there is something wrong with your code when the loops are enabled — it isn't all right.  What do you get?  What did you expect?  What's the difference?

Comment: you could print the `len` values. Maybe they're negative like -1 in some edge cases, where buf is `NULL`. Also declare `i` as `size_t` as well to avoid strange effects (signed/vs unsigned). Can you post the full output (with the prints) _as text_, not image

Comment: `ssize_t ret = new_sync_read(filp,buf,len,ppos);` you're not using `ret` but assuming `len` is read. Which could be wrong (end of buffer). Use `ret` in your crypt loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll attempt an answer.

**1. read part:**

You're relying on the *passed* length, not the *returned* length `ret` here:

```
ssize_t ret = new_sync_read(filp,buf,len,ppos);
```

so at the end of the buffer, when `len` is above the rest to read, `new_sync_read` returns `ret` which is *below* `len` and your loop writes outside the bounds.

My fix proposal:

```
ssize_t new_sync_read_crypt(struct file *filp, char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *ppos){

    ssize_t ret = new_sync_read(filp,buf,len,ppos);        
    size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < ret; i++)
        buf[i] -= 25;
    return ret;
}
```

I would also add `if (buf)` to protect the loop in case it's legal to pass `buf=NULL` and `len=-1`

**2. write part:**

The issue here is trickier.

```
ssize_t new_sync_write_crypt(struct file *filp, const char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *ppos){
    char *mybuf = buf;
```

here you're violating the `const` rule by casting a constant to a non-constant so you can encrypt. You cannot do that, for instance if the constant buffer is pointing to a *string literal*.

You have to create a copy using `malloc`

```
size_t new_sync_write_crypt(struct file *filp, const char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *ppos){
    char *mybuf = malloc(len);
    size_t i;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        mybuf[i] = buf[i]+25;
    }

    size_t r = new_sync_write(filp,mybuf,len,ppos);
    free(mybuf);
    return r;
}
```

Comment: thank you! read (cat) is okay, but write is killed(vi/ gedit) is killed still.

Comment: It's been killed still. And the log indicates that it is wrong when execute `mybuf[i] = buf[i] + 25`, the error is still `unable to handle kernel paging request at ********`

Comment: have you printed/checked the value of `len` ?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is not there. Thank you! After I do the same experiment with the same virtual machine on another computer, it goes all right. :)